Can I run hot tub wiring above ground, just below a ground level deck? Or does it need to be visible?
Can I run hot tub wiring in a conduit above ground, just underneath a ground level deck? Or does the conduit need to be visible?

It should be the same as having the conduit in the ground/inside a wall.

Your inspector might need to see the conduit as part of the inspection. Apart from that, you're welcome to run it under a deck, or even underground if you use the appropriate wire inside it. Since you'll probably be using THHN and basically all of that is dual-rated as THWN nowadays, it should be no big deal. Just ask your inspector to be certain.
